# 60 fps using css animation and translateX but not with percentage nor pixel

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations, css-transitions

#### Introduction

I'm trying to create a simple column transition using Bootstrap.

I will use it on very low-end devices so I'm using CSS transitions: **I want 60 FPS**.

#### Reproduction

- Full-screen here: https://lvd2m.csb.app
- Codesandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/bootstrap-animation-fps-translatex-with-percentages-lvd2m

#### How to reproduce

1. Open the full-screen app here: https://lvd2m.csb.app
2. What you see now is the animation with "slideWithPixels" CSS class
3. If you click the button "Kill animation" apparently nothing happens; maybe the mouse cursor hangs in the shape of a little hand for some time but animation is fluently, right?
4. If you click "Toggle CSS class" button now
5. you'll see animation jank/lag/freeze, call it what you like

#### Explanation

I'm using two CSS classes:

- **slideWithPixels** which has `transform: translateX(-350px)`
- **slideWithPercentage** which has `transform: translateX(-101%)` instead.

I wanna use `translateX(-101%)` because as you can see I'm using Bootstrap responsive grid and I don't know before which width my column has (is not fixed).

Pixels are not good because the animation can start too much before or too much after the viewport **0** pixel and percentage hangs as this example demonstrate.

**Why the percentage one hangs when the main thread is busy with javascript work?**

**What do you suggest to use instead of pixels and percentage?**

I'm lost with this problem.

Thank you all.

Comment: What does `requestAnimationFrame` has to do with css animations?

Comment: The `kill()` function does nothing with the animated sidebar. It just runs as many javascript `console.log()`s as it can within 2000ms (which freezes the browser, so not very useful ;) ). To stop the animation, you could toggle a class which has `animation: none;` in it. For better performance, you can either use the `3d` variants of the css transforms (which will trigger the user's GPU instead of CPU, or use a canvas element with the suggested `requestAnimationFrame` (optimizes timing of the calls).

Comment: @Philip the question is not about stop the animation, is about how to do for better performances on low-end devices if I need the responsive sidebar to start before the left part of the screen.

Comment: You could try `translate3d(-101%,0,0)` and `translate3d(0%,0,0)`. Then it's up to the browser to optimize the performance (rounding of precision, anti-aliasing, timing, etc). The other option is to use javascript to animate the object, but that might make it slower? (depending on the browsers implementation, the device, etc.)

Comment: The `kill()` function is a bit of an overkill for stress testing I think. In my case it run 20000+ times within 2secs and my browser/pc freezes to handle that first. The animation runs smoothly though, but interaction with the page is suspended until some time after running `kill()`. How the browser handles this JS overkill might be different on different devices and in different browsers. Best way to test smoothness is simply running it on an old device?

Comment: The `translate3d()` is the same as `translateX()`: jank on click! With pixel class one nope. My question is what alternative to `translateX(-100%)` I have.

Comment: The 3D one should trigger the user’s GPU (which might be faster and frees up the CPU). But besides that, I think that the kill function is not good way of testing what you want to test. Having said that, there’s always the option of using `left` attribute (either css animated, css transitioned or JavaScript).

Comment: * `margin-left` might also work btw